# linq order by a property which is an array?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

having this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new List<Tuple<string, int[]>>();

    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 8 })); //item 1
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 5 })); //item 2
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("b", new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 7 })); //item 3
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("b", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })); //item 4
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 1, 4, 9 })); //item 5

    var result = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2.OrderBy(y => y));
}
```

return `At least one object must implement IComparable.`

not really sure how to write that linq so i would get this result

1. item 5
2. item 2
3. item 1
4. item 4
5. item 3

Comment: You can provide your custom `IComparer` to the `OrderBy` or `ThenBy` function (by passing as the second *[third if you think it's an extension method]* parameter). You'd need to implement an `IComparer` to let the system know how to compare the values of `Item2`. There's no built-in comparison for array types (how is `int[]{1,1,4,9}` sorted before `int[]{1,2,3,4}`?)

Comment: What specific properties of the array do you want to sort by?

Comment: @Jcl I think he is sorting first by the string value of `item1`alphabetically then the array (in some fashion). That is how we get `{1,1,4,9}` before `{1,2,3,4}`

Comment: @tyh yes, but for the `ThenBy` part, he's feeding a "sorted array of ints" (`Item2.OrderBy(...)`), which the system doesn't know how to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom `IComparer<int[]>` is what you want here. Here is how I would write it. This will look at the individual values until it finds a difference. If no difference is found before reaching the end of either array, then it returns based on the length of the array with the metric that the shorter array is smaller.

```
public class ArrayComparer : IComparer<int[]>
{
    public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < x.Length && i < y.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i])
                return x[i] - y[i];
        }

        return x.Length - y.Length;
    }
}
```

Using subtractions for the comparisons works well with how the return values of `IComparer` are specified.

To use it you would simply write

```
var result = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2.OrderBy(y => y).ToArray(), new ArrayComparer());
```

Comment: That's definitely more optimized than mine, but should be equally effective

Comment: Indeed they are similar. Subtractions for comparisons work very well with `IComparer` when working with numeric values.

Comment: Yep, I just wrote it off my mind without thinking too much (actually wrote it in SO editor... then made a test program to check the result :-) ). I'd however check the lengths after the int comparisons... should "1,2,3,2" be higher than "1,2,4"? (that should be in the requirements that we don't know even if we asked for them many times ;-) )

Comment: The first statement should catch if they are differing lengths and return properly. I added edited the answer to say it was an assumption based on incomplete information. If the OP provides that information, I can modify my answer appropriately.

Comment: I'd assume that the one with the highest value has higher precedence, disregarding the length except if the first numbers are equal... but yes, those are just assumptions and it's the OP who should specify :-)

Comment: I just changed it around a bit to check the lengths after the compares. It should match what you are saying now. `{1, 2, 4}` will be considered greater than `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and `{1, 2, 3}` will be considered less than `{1, 2, 3, 4}` which does make a bit more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wild guessing since you are not specifying the requirements (why would an array come before another array), but taking the comments, I'll provide an answer that "should" work (off my mind and not really optimized):

```
class ArrayComparer : IComparer<int[]>
{
  public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.Length && i < y.Length; i++)
    {
      if (x[i] > y[i])
        return 1;
      if (y[i] > x[i])
        return -1;
    }
    if (y.Length > x.Length)
      return -1;
    else if (y.Length < x.Length)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
var result = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Item2.OrderBy(y => y).ToArray(), new ArrayComparer());
```

I actually tested it and this is the result:

```
a -> 1,1,4,9 // item 5
a -> 1,2,6,5 // item 2
a -> 1,4,7,8 // item 1
b -> 1,2,3,4 // item 4
b -> 1,4,7,7 // item 3
```

Comment: It's fine, as long as the answers helped you, and best of all, if you understood why it was a problem in first place, and how to solve it if it appears in the future. That's what Stack Overflow is about :-)

Comment: i never really implemented a icomparer so this one is a good opportunity to learn how to do it next time :-)

Comment: It does suck having to chose between two good answers. I'm just glad we were able to help.

Answer (score 0):

this seem to be doing what I want

```
var result = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
                 .ThenBy(x => string.Join(",", x.Item2.OrderBy(y => y)));
```

and will only work with same number of digit ...

Comment: This could be slow so if someone have a better way of doing it, go.

Comment: That's an alphabetical sort of the strings: "1,4,7,8", "1,2,6,5", etc. If it fits you, ok, but if you ever need any two-digit value on the int array part, it'll probably not work as expected

Comment: if you define in your question how you want those int arrays to be sorted, I can try implement an `IComparer` for you, it should be really easy

Comment: @jcl, if i try these 2; { 10, 1, 100, 1002 } and { 10, 1, 100, 1001 }. it seem to be working. hmm do you have an example in mind where it would not work?

Comment: As I said, it depends on how you want those arrays to be sorted. "Why is item5 sorted before item2" in your result? Is it the sum of the values? The one with the largest value first?

Comment: Negatives might also break the sorting as would possibly arrays of differing lengths.

Comment: Try `1 19 1 1` and `1 2 1 1` I agree with JCL implement `IComparer` in this case if you want an actual numeric comparison.

Comment: @BradD, only positive value

Comment: @Jcl, mostly, if I have this `{ 9, 3, 2, 1 } and { 8, 3, 2, 1 }` I want `{ 8, 3, 2, 1 }` first since sorting it would give `{ 1, 2, 3, 8 } and { 1, 2, 3, 9 }`

Comment: @Fredou that doesn't answer the question: why would `{1,2,3,8}` come before `{1,2,3,9}`? Because the sum of the values is lower? That doesn't have a "default reasoning", you need to know why

Comment: Are the `int[]` always the same length?

Comment: Are you sure that you are correct in the last x.Item2.OrderBy()? If "Item2" had "1" as the last digit in the array, would you want it to come before or after "Item5"?

Comment: @jcl, because of the sequence of the number.

Comment: @BradD, yes by the item1 but no if item1 is different. so "a" could have 4 elements but "b" could have 2 and "c" could have none, etc.

Comment: @Fredou a sequence doesn't have a default comparison, you basically want the one with the highest number first, but that's not "default"

Comment: @Fredou I've added an answer with an IComparer that if I've done it right (not really sure), should do what you want, even with variable int array sizes

Answer (score 0):

For my answer I created a custom compare that compares the Tuple type and also SequenceCompare to generically compare arrays of any type.  I believe this will be quite fast.

This also handles arrays of different sizes just fine -- with the longer one being "larger".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new List<Tuple<string, int[]>>();

    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 8 })); //item 1
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 5 })); //item 2
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 2, 6  })); //item 2
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 2,  5 })); //item 2
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1,  6, 5 })); //item 2
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] {  2, 6, 5 })); //item 2
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("b", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })); //item 4
    test.Add(new Tuple<string, int[]>("a", new int[] { 1, 1, 4, 9 })); //item 5

    var result = test.OrderBy(x => x,new CustomComp()) ;

    result.Dump();
}


public class CustomComp : IComparer<Tuple<string, int[]>>
{
   public int Compare(Tuple<string, int[]> x,Tuple<string, int[]> y)
   {
     int strR = string.Compare(x.Item1,y.Item1);
     if (strR == 0)
       return x.Item2.SequenceCompare(y.Item2);
     else
     return strR;
   }
}

static class Compare
{
  public static int SequenceCompare<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> x, IEnumerable<TSource> y)
  {
    return SequenceCompare(x,y,System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<TSource>.Default);
  }

  public static int SequenceCompare<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> x, IEnumerable<TSource> y, IComparer<TSource> comparer)
  {
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> xe = x.GetEnumerator(), ye = y.GetEnumerator())
    {
      while (true)
      {
        bool next1 = xe.MoveNext();
        bool next2 = ye.MoveNext();

        // Are not of same length. longer one >
        if (next1 != next2)
        {
            if (next1 == true) return 1;
            return -1;
        }

        // Both finished -- equal
        if (!next1) return 0;

        int result = comparer.Compare(xe.Current, ye.Current);

        if (result != 0) return result;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```